# Load testing with Visual Studio 2013 passing parameters to virtual users

Tags: visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I am new to Load testing with Visual Studio. I have a website with 16 different pages. I created 4 different web performance tests like one each for 4 pages. So now my 4 web performance tests covers most of the web site. Please note that each web test is recorded with a login and logout(I can not avoid this since all pages are secured). In my website if a user tries to login second time(if already logged in), it detects and show an Error page. I wanted to do a load test by combining all these web tests. I have done that. But majority of the tests failed because of virtual users concurrent login operations. Reponse Url validation rule fails for most of them. Can any one suggest a good strategy for load test. I know how to supply parameters from datasource. I have a csv file with user name and passwords. I can do this for each web test. But how to do this for a load test. May be I am thinking wrong. Is it possible to pass parameters to load test directly(means for each virtual user)? Please have your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If your web site only allows a user to be logged in from one place at a time then your tests need to be written to avoid (see note) having the same user (attempting to be) logged in more than once. A common way of doing this is to split the available users into non-overlapping groups and each test is then data driven with a different group.

Load tests are not data driven. A Visual Studio load test is a test environment that calls other tests and collects data about their performance. Load tests work very well with and collect lots of data from Web Performance tests. They also work with unit and Coded UI tests, but less data is collected.

The phrase "data driven load test" might be regarded as short way of saying "load test that calls (one or more) data driven web tests".

---

Note: Some tests might require the web site's handling of multiple logins by the same user to be explored.